# Functions not reading from linked list

Tags: c

I have the following code where I can add a node and print all current nodes in a linked list. When I try to use the Query function to plug in an ID Rank and print only those I get nothing and the same with Modify, I enter in a ID and Amount to change and nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct employeeData {
    int EMP_ID;
    char name[20];
    int dept;
    int rank;
    int salary;

    struct employeeData* next;
};

void initializeList(struct employeeData** List);
void add(struct employeeData** List);
void Delete(struct employeeData** List);
void modify(struct employeeData** List);
void query(struct employeeData** List);
void print(struct employeeData** List);

int main() {
    struct employeeData* myList = NULL;
    int inputNUM, myListInput;
    // initializeList(myList);
    while (inputNUM != 0) {
        printf("Please select an option from the following menu\n");
        printf("1) To add a new employee \n");
        printf("2) To delete an employee \n");
        printf("3) To modify an employee record \n");
        printf("4) To query employees by rank \n");
        printf("5) To print all employee information \n\n");
        printf("Enter 0 to stop \n\n");

        printf("Input: ");
        scanf("%d", &inputNUM);

        printf("\n");

        if (inputNUM == 1) {
            add(&myList);
        }
        if (inputNUM == 2) {
            Delete(&myList);
        }
        if (inputNUM == 3) {
            modify(&myList);
        }
        if (inputNUM == 4) {
            query(&myList);
        }
        if (inputNUM == 5) {
            print(&myList);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
void initializeList(struct employeeData **List)

{

FILE *ifp;
ifp = fopen("empInfo.txt","r");

struct employeeData *Temp = NULL;
Temp = (struct employeeData*)malloc(sizeof(struct employeeData));

while (ifp != NULL)
{
    fscanf(ifp, "%d %s %d %d %d", &Temp->EMP_ID, Temp->name, &Temp->dept,
&Temp->rank, &Temp->salary);

    Temp->next;
}

while (*List->next != NULL)
{
    *List = *List->next;
}

*List-next = Temp;

fclose(ifp);

}

*/

void add(struct employeeData** List) {
    struct employeeData* Temp = NULL;
    Temp = (struct employeeData*)malloc(sizeof(struct employeeData));

    printf("Please enter the information of the employee: ");
    scanf("%d %s %d %d %d", &Temp->EMP_ID, Temp->name, &Temp->dept, &Temp->rank,
          &Temp->salary);

    printf("\n");
    Temp->next = NULL;
    if (*List == NULL) {
        *List = Temp;
    }

    else {
        struct employeeData* last = *List;

        while (last->next != NULL) {
            last = last->next;
        }

        last->next = Temp;
    }
}

void Delete(struct employeeData** List) {
    int TEMPID = NULL;

    struct employeeData* Temp = *List;

    printf("Please enter the EMP_ID for the employee that you would like to be "
           "deleted: ");
    scanf("%d", &TEMPID);

    while (Temp->EMP_ID != TEMPID) {
        if (Temp->next->EMP_ID == TEMPID) {
            break;
        } else {
            Temp = Temp->next;
        }
    }

    if (Temp->next->next == NULL) {
        free(Temp->next);
        *List = Temp;
    } else {
        struct employeeData* connect = Temp;
        struct employeeData* del = Temp->next;
        connect = Temp->next->next;
        Temp->next = connect;
        free(del);
        *List = Temp;
    }
}

void modify(struct employeeData** List) {
    int TEMPID = 0, NewSAL = 0;

    struct employeeData* Temp = *List;

    printf("Please enter the EMP_ID and new salary for the employee that you "
           "would like to modify: ");
    scanf("%d", &TEMPID, &NewSAL);

    while (Temp->EMP_ID != TEMPID) {
        Temp = Temp->next;
    }

    Temp->salary = NewSAL;
    *List = Temp;
}

void query(struct employeeData** List) {
    int TEMPID = NULL;

    printf("Please provide the rank that you would like to query: ");
    scanf("%d", &TEMPID);

    struct employeeData* Temp = *List;
    while (Temp != NULL) {
        if (Temp->EMP_ID == TEMPID) {
            printf("%s \n", Temp->name);
            Temp = Temp->next;
        } else {
            Temp = Temp->next;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void print(struct employeeData** List) {
    struct employeeData* Temp = *List;
    while (Temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d %s %d %d %d \n", Temp->EMP_ID, Temp->name, Temp->dept,
               Temp->rank, Temp->salary);

        Temp = Temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify this question? This reads as, "I have a problem with my code, can you debug it?" You will be more successful here if you ask specific questions.

Comment: It looks like you are never filling your list due to problems pointed out below (and probably others). Please show your compile string, warnings, program input, and runtime errors or warnings received. Also, confirm in a debugger that you in fact have data in your linked list (for debugging, just keep a global int counter that is incremented +1 for each successful add to list)

Answer (score 0):

This are the error reported by GCC 4.9.1 with **-Wall**:

```
E:\test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
E:\test.cpp:23:19: warning: unused variable 'myListInput' [-Wunused-variable]
     int inputNUM, myListInput;
                   ^
E:\test.cpp: In function 'void modify(employeeData**)':
E:\test.cpp:153:33: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     scanf("%d", &TEMPID, &NewSAL);
```

The second report if about the line: `scanf("%d", &TEMPID, &NewSAL);`, the `scanf` function is expecting two format specifier because of the two parameters to read `TEMPID` and `NewSAL`.

Changed by: `scanf("%d %d", &TEMPID, &NewSAL);`

This are the error reported by Clang 3.5 with **-Wall**:

```
E:\test.cpp:23:19: warning: unused variable 'myListInput' [-Wunused-variable]
    int inputNUM, myListInput;
                  ^
E:\test.cpp:23:9: warning: variable 'inputNUM' is used uninitialized whenever function 'main' is called [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
    int inputNUM, myListInput;
    ~~~~^~~~~~~~
E:\test.cpp:25:12: note: uninitialized use occurs here
    while (inputNUM != 0) {
           ^~~~~~~~
E:\test.cpp:23:17: note: initialize the variable 'inputNUM' to silence this warning
    int inputNUM, myListInput;
                ^
                 = 0
```

You are using an uninitialized variable in the while condition (this is undefined behavior, anything could happen): `while (inputNUM != 0) {`, in this case the solution is initializing the variable (eg: with a value `!= 0`), for entering in the while loop.

**Recommendation** always compile with the maximum level of warning available.